# The teacher's formula: why can't people on Stack Overflow accept it

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

So this is a serious question I am asking here, and it is something I have a really hard time wrapping my head around, and it is also the reason I think a vast amount of my questions get negative votes.

I want to know why people on Stack Overflow can not understand the concept of "the teacher's formula"?

What I mean by that is as follows:

I grew up in America and went to schools in America. One of the things I learned early on in school life was that the teacher's formula, is the only correct formula. The end result is not what matters.

So for example if the teacher showed a specific way to do a math problem and you got homework relating to that math problem, then you tried to do that homework in a way other than which the teacher showed you, you got it marked wrong even if your answer was right. Why? Because you did not do it the way the teacher said to do it.

Sometimes, it's the formula that matters, not the end result.

So why is it that people on  Stack Overflow have such a hard time with this?

If I ask a question and specifically state "I am looking for an end result such as .... but I need to avoid using the popular method of ...." almost guaranteed someone will come along, downvote my question, close it as duplicate, and link to a question in which all replies are exactly the method I asked NOT to use.

And then of course getting them to reopen the question is like pulling teeth. Often times its a huge debate of "you need to learn to think how to use these solutions in your own problems without specific code" completely ignoring the fact I am specifically asking NOT TO USE the method they are trying to shove down my throat.

This is programming we are talking about, there is rarely one way of doing things.

How are us question askers suppose to deal with this? Should we not be asking such specific questions and simply accept any method no matter what as long as it returns the end result? Why can we not simply be trying to learn a new method of achieving things?

S.O., at times is very frustrating and it seems those who have been around the longest, are the quickest to vote things duplicate.

Comment: Ehm ... if you ask a question, the answerers are the teachers, right?

Comment: If you have an specific example you can link to it might be better than this general rant. Just because you want it done one specific way doesn't mean it's possible. Programming is not math and the same rules don't apply.

Comment: Also, please read up on the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/295232).

Comment: Requesting a specific way to solve a problem is not in itself a reason to downvote and closevote if the request is reasonable. Can you show an example please? Questioning the asker's formula in comments is perfectly OK, though, and one of the reasons why this place is such a great learning resource - it often helps uncover incorrect preconceptions and bad practices.

Comment: @Glorfindel I think that XY problem goes both ways. Recently I had a question asking to use a php method of sorting through a series of mysql select statements. I specifically new that returning the results via an mysql statement would not work as the only way to do it would be to do a full table join which would result in tens of millions of rows of results. Despite my telling people this, my question was still closed as duplicate and directed to a mysql full table join solution. Sometimes, those of us programming know not to do it a certain way, because we have specs of what we work with.

Comment: If it's as you say, it was an incorrect closing and you can fight it using comments, or even a Meta question laying out your case (ideally, calmly and matter-of-factly).

Comment: @Pekka웃 and Paulie_D I'd show you examples if I could, but I generally fight hard to get my questions reopened when they are closed, so despite why they get closed, I generally get the back. Its just a burden at times.

Comment: Questions on Meta are better received when they aren't long rants. Try getting to the point, show examples when possible, and try to avoid insinuations like *"why people on stackoverflow can not understand [...]"*.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but ... a large portion of SO users aren't American in the first place. I can't speak for what the school system in every country out there is like, but let's suppose we're going for a universally understood experience here. If you don't explain the constraints you're faced with, how do you expect others to know what they are?

Comment: Being forced to do something one way for an arbitrary reason of a teacher said so is bad practice. They didn't teach that in our schools, instead as long as you got the correct answer and showed how you got the correct answer, you got marks. For SO, constraints sometimes exist, but unless a good reason is given for these constraints, why should we stick to them when there are better ways? Would you ask a mechanic to fix your car, but can't use a spanner, due to an arbitrary reason? Unlikely

Comment: "Questions on Meta are better received when they aren't long rants." my question related to SO not meta. I didn't expect such a negative response from a discussion based topic, but hey.. I suppose we can all see this as me having a rant. I actually didn't post specifics, cause I wasn't really thinking about a specific situation... it was intended to be a general discussion. I am just on a roll for bad questions this week it seems no matter where I post on SO

Comment: SO is no longer a place where a professional programmer like yourself can easily get an answer without doing much work.  That all ended 3 years ago when programmers without any training or experience got empowered to ask their questions.  You have to go the extra distance to ensure your question doesn't resemble those of the 95% crowd, the kind that can so often be addressed by applying a teacher's blue-print solution.  Not that likely you'll get a useful answer but you can easily invest the time to earn some rep to spend on a bounty.

Comment: @Bruce Mind you, downvotes are different on meta. They're used primarily to express disagreement.

Comment: Ironically (since you ask why people here don’t understand the concept of the teacher’s formula), you seem to have trouble grasping the concept of the teacher’s formula: it’s an *educational device*. Its use is restricted to a specific, artificial scenario. You can’t just apply it nilly-willy to other situations and demand that people respect it. (It’s also a fairly poor educational device; competent teachers who have studied modern didactics don’t need to resort to it.)

Comment: *you got it marked wrong even if your answer was right.* Not sure what school you went to but that has never happened to me and I live is the USA.  I hardly ever showed work or did it my own way and was never marked down unless the answer was incorrect.  A teacher that forces you to do it there way and no other is IMHO, not a very good teacher.

Comment: Most educators realized that was a pretty limiting way to teach, which is why Common Core is the standard now.

Comment: *"simply be trying to learn a new method of achieving things"* isn't really a good fit for SO. As you say, many problems have multiple possible answers, but asking a new question for each one isn't going to scale (*"how do I do X?"*, *"how do I do X other than Y?"*, *"how do I do X other than Y or Z?"*, ...). If you don't have (or don't *explain*) a good reason not to use the methods already available on SO, it's perfectly reasonable to point you to them. If you just want other approaches out of interest, consider a bounty on the existing question.

Comment: Sounds like you had some really terrible teachers...

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm guessing you don't have much experience with common core. In common core, if you do math any other way than what is explained you get it wrong. My kids got problems like 12 + 13 wrong for lining them up and adding as you and I were taught. They had to break the problem down to 10 + 2 + 10 + 3 and then separately add 10 + 10, and then separately add 2 + 3, and then combine, or the answer is wrong. This is the common core way.

Comment: @Bruce None what so ever except the felling that I do not want to.

Comment: I have under 300 points, and it drops more day by day because I can't seem to get this damn "how to ask a question" thing down. I don;t have enough points to have asked any questions relating to "should I modify some users post if it changes the intent but makes more sense"... so not sure how this could even remotely be a duplicate of such a topic, but I am tired of trying to understand this site. In the last couple weeks it has become more me trying to learn stackexchange sites and less about coding, and thats the opposite effect this site should have on a user.

Comment: The analogy does not hold true.  A teacher has authority over students, so they can request that something can only be done in a certain way.  A question asker on the other hand, has no such authority.

Answer (score 19):

> So why is it that people on stackoverflow have such a hard time with
>   this?

Because they don't have to. If you don't present it as a homework problem (you probably don't want to to avoid the instant downvotes) then the answer to "How to do X?" may very well be "Don't do X, do Y or Z instead".

You have to make sure to be specific enough that the community understands why a particular limitation of yours exists. Depending on your provided details, the community might conclude even that your limitation is bogus and you need to work around it. That's your responsibility as a question asker.

If I say something like "I want to do X, but it can't be done Y way" then you have to expect people to ask "Why? What makes that so?" because often, people assume limitations that don't exist or are wrong about limitations they think exist, but don't really.

As for downvotes, we get thousands of questions that are more or less thinly veiled attempts at getting us to solve someone's homework in entirety, which is not what this site is for. You have to make sure your question differs from that. There are thousands of "I need to do X, but in the very specific way Y - everything else is not allowed".

Comment: I think the "teacher's formula" thing was just a rhetorical device to underscore that sometimes OPs have good reasons to use exactly the approach they request in their question

Comment: @Pekka웃 The same principle applies there: If your question is not specific enough to explain clearly why those won't work, then "Do Y instead" is a valid answer in some cases. "But I can't do Y" without an explaination as to why is invalid, imo.

Comment: alternative suggestions aren't exactly on-topic answers however. The answer might instead be "not possible".

Comment: @Gimby Usually these answers then go "Its not possible with Y due to [reason] and [reason], but Z may work [insert solution]" which is on topic imo.

Comment: @magisch Just as long as Z is not JQuery ;)

Answer (score 14):

> "I am looking for an end result such as .... but I need to avoid using the popular method of ...."

You might have very good reasons not to use the popular method, but *unless* you specify **why**, this is just another disguise of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/295232). Most answerers here have more reputation than you, and *assume* that means they have more experience than you.

Answer (score 4):

Many question are like *"how do I do XX using YY"* with no explanation of why the answer must use *"YY"*. Additionally, Stack Overflow is about creating a Q&A resource, not simply answering the basic original question. In the future people may ask *"how do I do XX"*  or *"how do I do XX using ZZ"*. Hence multiple answers with multiple methods are useful.

Comment: Ironically your argument, is my very reason for the question and we agree while disagreeing. The problem is, I frequently see canned closed questions because there is A given method with no alternatives offered. I suppose that's the nature of the game to some extent when asking duplicate questions, but sometimes that is the point, exactly what you say, to create multiple answers instead of a single question with a single answer marked as correct and unless someone comes along and adds another answer to age old questions, which seems unlikely, one answer remains.