# Is Stack Overflow a good place for self learners?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

My journey on to Meta Stack Overflow started today after I asked a question and not five minutes after posting, it got marked as duplicate and closed. I tried asking it differently, but I quickly learned that I had been banned from asking questions because I had asked too many bad questions.

I am a self-learner who's working through some courses and books online and since I don't have access to many people who are programmers, I took to Stack Overflow to look for help in my quest to become a better programmer.

Some of my questions were truly bad like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124528/why-do-i-have-so-many-untracked-files-on-git) about Git (forgive me I didn't know better!), some were [genuine confusions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072519/why-doesnt-the-value-of-my-boolean-change-in-a-while-loop) I had and didn't realize the mistake until days later (at that point I did come back and answer my own question clarifying where the confusion had been).

The [question that got me banned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494123/how-do-i-implement-a-append-in-linear-and-constant-time-on-a-linked-list-in-pyth?noredirect=1#comment114040439_64494123), however, was one "homework" question that I wanted some feedback on (in my view, it did follow the guidelines for asking a good question). I think I could have searched better (I also think the Stack Overflow search engine is not super good at finding helpful questions). Like I mentioned above, this question got quickly flagged as a duplicate and closed. Not only that, but the question that I got redirected to didn't help me, and as a beginner it only raised more questions about new things I didn't understand!

Now, I know there's been a lot of debate on asking homework questions on Stack Overflow. I just spent some time going over [how to ask/answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), as well as [this duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/stack-overflow-and-homework-questions).

I even found this (unfortunately, in my opinion) downvoted question about [the teacher's formula](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334505/the-teachers-formula-why-cant-people-on-stack-overflow-accept-it), which led me to [this poorly named one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels), and then to learn about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). At this point, I have read enough to understand where I could have done better.

However, I am still left with a bitter taste in my mouth because as a self-learner who doesn't have access to professors or professional programmers, I feel like Stack Overflow might not be the friendliest place for me. So it leads me to ask, **is Stack Overflow a good place for self-learners?** If not, then what is the place for a self-learner like me who tries his best at answering his own questions, but isn't always able to?

Comment: I'm a self-learner, and I think I did passably OK on the site. So yes, it's a good site for self-learners. But that doesn't mean it's a good site to post just about anything.

Comment: If too many of your questions are being closed as duplicates, you are probably not doing enough research first before posting questions.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/63530800) - this is probably salvageable if you attempt to debug your code and post an error message. [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/59040810) - you probably can't fix this so edit the other one.

Comment: SO is a *great* place for self-learners (I'm one too). But I did use SO for years before even having an account, because even then all my questions were already answered. (to be fair, I think I learned more by answering since then)

Comment: Luckily you noticed the rate limit early and seek help while your total score is borderline. Others continue to post poor questions and dig themselves into a permanent question ban.

Comment: Of the "why" it is like that, having particpated in review queues, I must concurr that therte are a really big number of question, _each hour_ that are just homework dumped without any compassion for potential readers / answerers. I think we do a good job by asking minimal debug / explanation / [mcve] in these cases instead of keeping and "answer" the question directly  (or rather, do the homework instead of OP)

Comment: also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: You and I seem to have a different definition of "self-learning". Self implies you; you will be teaching yourself, through study, research and experimentation. Stack Overflow is amazingly helpful in the research department as it is literally a tome of knowledge. It is also entirely unstructured except for a tag system; there is no start or end, there is no index, there are no chapters or paragraphs. You pull from it specifics that you need, it is not a guide of any kind. So it sucks for study, I would still get a good book to have a well-prepared starting off point to branch out from.

Comment: thanks for the feedback to everyone who's replied. like I mentioned in the original post I recognize that my first few questions on the site were genuinely effortless and poorly written and researched. I think my qualm now is with two things 1) I have often searched for the answers on SO before posting, however, as @Gimby mentions, since there is no index I sometimes don't find what I am looking for or don't know how to look for my question; so assuming it's not there I post thinking it will be a good question. Any tips on becoming a better SO researcher?

Comment: my second problem was more with the teacher's formula problem. Sometimes I will ask a question because the methods I have found are beyond my knowledge, and so I assume it is fair game to ask a question that is simpler and more beginner friendly. I see now that there's a lot of disagreement as to how or whether to ask these questions, so I don't know if there is a solution for this. Again, I assume experience will be a great teacher, but it would be great if I got asked for clarification before my questions got closed. alas!

Comment: Yes, it is not easy to find the right keywords for searching in [20,330,120 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

Comment: @alpablo20 A key point in asking the question in SO is that the questions do not depend on the expertise of the OP, we are only interested in the question itself, so in SO there are no questions for beginners or experts.

Comment: @alpablo20 Or would you like the answers to depend on the OP? in my case I would not like it since in the answers I will see different perspectives. My recommendation is that you get involved with the site more: for example, check the questions every day even if they are not your questions, if you can try to answer them, search by concepts and not by phrases, and use SO as the last resource and take the largest amount of time possible to write the quality question.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm not sure I follow your point, could you clarify? I think there should be some sort of distinction because as a somewhat beginner, sometimes as much as I want to undderstand an answer or follow a thread I just simply don't have the background knowledge to do so. This is not from a desire not to want to do work, but as someone working by myself I often don't even know how to begin looking for things.

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah, that second point makes sense. I think in my experience it came down to two things 1) inexperience and lack of effort at first and now that I understand SO better I think I still find it intimidating and discouraging when I think I am making an effort but my questions kept getting closed. I know it's not a teching website, but sometimes I do wish for a little more compassion and understanding. alas!

Comment: @alpablo20 1) I am self-learner, 2) SO is not a tutoring service but rather a collection of knowledge, and that knowledge is shared with everyone regardless of their level of knowledge (it will depend on the interest, not only that they want to learn but also the effort what that implies, try to understand it).

Comment: @alpablo20 Precisely because our actions do not depend on the OP do not ask us for compassion, when one votes for a question (either a DV or UV) they are not saying that the OP is bad or not but that the question is bad for the site since it does not comply With the rules, when your question is closed as a duplicate they are indicating that that question has already been answered. In academic life, it is not the "who" but the "what" is of interest.

Comment: @alpablo20: _"sometimes as much as I want to undderstand an answer or follow a thread I just simply don't have the background knowledge to do so"_ -- as a self-learner, you _must_ develop the skill of taking a problem that you don't understand and breaking it down into smaller parts. The parts will fall into one of three categories: small enough to be problems you already know the answer to; small enough for you to be able to recognize how existing answers solve the problem; or, small enough to be able to be stated clearly, concisely, and uniquely on Stack Overflow so someone can help.

Comment: @alpablo20 What I think is that you try to be a self-learner but you don't know what that implies. He tells you about his own experience: When I was in school, my teacher gave me a book to learn a topic that he did not teach me and told me that my task is to explain what the book was about, that is self-learner since I had to read first the book, what I did not understand I had to investigate it in the library. In other words, the teacher told me to read a book but in reality I had to read many. The same is in SO: do not look for a single question but you must read many.

Comment: @eyllanesc " you try to be a self-learner but you don't know what that implies" I am not sure if you're saying that about me. In any case, yeah, I mean many of us don't know how to self-learn and we are learning something while learning how to learn. That's what I meant with compassion, more benefit of the doubt. If I see a question that is poorly researched but that could give something interesting, I'd rather ask for clarification before just closing it. There are different levels of learning.

Comment: @eyllanesc And I think this goes back to the discussion on the teacher's formula. Yeah, the way a question is asked may not be the best, but we sometimes don't want the best solution, we want something else and that aids in learning. I was introduced to SO in college as the site where you could come and ask your coding questions, but I am now learning that that's not the case and there is a specific sub-culture w its own rules to follow.

Comment: @alpablo20 I just said it for you. As I already pointed out, do not ask for compassion since here we are not interested in "who asks" but "the question". My recommendation is that you focus on one thing: Learn to self-learner: learn to research, for example in search sites: use keywords, learn what each resource is for (for example, what SO is for), check the documentation official, books and tutorials etc.

Comment: @alpablo20 Exact: Many times there are many people who do not know what each resource is for or at least it is not clear in pointing out that it gives false expectations to other people.

Comment: *it got marked as duplicate and closed.* - You seem to see this as a problem.  Within 5 minutes, someone found and pointed you at an already-written answer to a related question, which hopefully provides / includes the answer to your question.  Or at worst a pointer to what the relevant concepts are that you can start googling.  If you're here to *learn*, not to have solutions to your specific problem handed to you on a silver platter, you'll have to be more specific about why having someone find an existing Q&A for you is a problem for you.

Comment: @PeterCordes it *was* a problem for me, because i didn't see much feedback on why my question was poorly written or researched beyond it's a duplicate. I read thru the quesiton i was directed to and didn't find the answer I was looking for. No, I don't expect the answer on a silver platter, but if I am telling my question is bad, I would appreciate some feedback on how to make it better.

Comment: Re: how to search: I usually use google for `site:stackoverflow.com  foo bar` when looking for duplicates to existing questions.  Of course it helps tremendously to already know the answer, so I can use search terms that I expect to see in a useful answer but weren't in the question.  (And maybe I'll even have a memory of a specific canonical Q&A in mind.  In the lower-traffic tags I follow like [assembly], maybe even remembering who wrote it so I can include their username in the search.  Often myself; it's convenient having a fairly rare last name :)

Comment: @PeterCordes See! This is what I am talking about, I wouldn't have known how to look for stuff like this before. There's a learning curve to how to look for answers and as someone who was told in college that SO was the place to come ask your coding questions, I was surprised when my coding questions kept getting closed. I mean I am still learning how to do things better, but at this point I've spent the whole day on SO learning the rules and expectations and that takes away from precious learning time.

Comment: **Duplicate does *not* imply poorly written**. It *just* means already answered.  Sometimes it's not even reasonable to expect the asker to have found the duplicate, because it's running into the same problem a different way. i.e. they could only have found the duplicate if they already knew the answer. People that *do* know the answer can find a duplicate for you instead of spending more time and cluttering SO with redundant content. Of course that's the ideal; more often duplicate questions aren't interesting and the person should have googled and/or read a tutorial before taking up my time.

Comment: As someone who follows new questions so I can answer (or close / downvote) them, it's not fun to see the same question for the 20th or 100th time, so real basics of how a given language works (like syntax for array indexing) is typically low quality as well as a duplicate. If *that's* what was happening with your questions, yeah, you need to know enough basics from reading through a tutorial before you know enough to ask an interesting question that doesn't amount to "write a custom tutorial for me".

Comment: A standard comment of mine: "Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title."

Comment: I would like to add that apart from the proficiency to write good/bad questions, according to my experience in SO there is  a big chance that a question will be downvoted, and severely even if its fair and well explained according to the site rules. I fully agree and support the SO approach to build a useful site that holds neat and reachable content for the programmers, however most of the times and find my questions and others severely downvoted not understanding why.

Comment: As far as I understand sometimes its because questions are too large and deep that explanation might take a while. People that dont want to take the effort to understand the question directly downvote as its not a direct simple compilation problem to solve. However, many times if you read the question, you can realize it is the effort of the asker to explain the problem properly the reason it was downvoted.

Comment: I use Google to search, and then use the StackOverflow hits. Google, of course, is much better for searching than the StackOverflow search engine. But StackOverflow is basically read-only for me because I don't want to deal with the power trippers. I understand the desire to have a useful site, but I don't think running it like it were Singapore is the answer.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay: _"there is a big chance that a question will be downvoted, and severely even if its fair and well explained"_ -- for what it's worth, it's my observation that the exact opposite happens as well. I.e. questions, even patently terrible ones, are often upvoted for no apparent reason. Voting is a crapshoot; since the community as a whole has divergent opinion about what makes a good or bad question or answer, you will see the same divergence in the voting patterns. "Iffy" Q&A get seemingly-random or offsetting voting, but in the long run, the clearly good and clearly bad get ...

Comment: ... the votes they deserve. The most important features are a) good questions get good answers, and b) it's easy to find the good answers to good questions when you have the same question. It's debatable whether SO succeeds on the second point, but I think it does pretty well on the first point, even with all the messiness that comes from the voting.

Comment: Re your "homework question", it normally doesn't matter if the problem to be solved is from homework or not. But it's asking for feedback on complete and (presumably) working code, like "*Is it actually constant-time? Did I miss some edge cases? Is this good code?*", which imo is better suited for [codereview.SE] than StackOverflow.

Comment: The close voters should be ashamed of themselves.  Talking about Stack Overflow's goal isn't an answer to this question.  Self-learners are always coming to the site and putting up a discussion about the goals of what Stack Overflow was what we *thought* it should be some six or seven years ago is not even close to an answer on this discussion.

Comment: @Bergi:  **Do not post your homework question to Code Review.**  [Please peruse this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/9874), and do not consider Code Review as an option until you have thoroughly understood what role Code Review is playing in this ecosystem.

Comment: @Makoto I understand your concerns, I did not mean to imply that all homework questions should go to Code Review. I believe to know what role CR is playing and what is on-topic there, and I think that the OP's [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494123/how-do-i-implement-a-append-in-linear-and-constant-time-on-a-linked-list-in-pyth) would have fit better there (with adjusted title and text of course).

Comment: As @Steve Bennet said, *It sucks when you only have a vague notion*, I think SO isn't the best place to ask/answer questions in that kind of situation, instead online programmer communities like HackClub or others are a better place to learn programming as they are **not Q&A**

Comment: Is it a good place? Not really. Is there a better place? If quickly resolving your issue is your priority then not really. Stack has proven to provide quick answers time and time again but you have to learn how to play the "stack game". The most important and crucial part of it - stay on point and keep other people on point. Otherwise you'll have everyone trying to shove their preferences and habits down your piehole, don't give them a chance. Break down your issue into singular concise questions, post minimal examples, discard everything else, don't mention why or what for, only the how.

Comment: Stackoverflow has been *crucial* for me since I started using it 11 years ago ... this is a community of experience programmers who are quick to help people with questions. Please participate and this will make the site more useful for everyone.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Important caveat upfront:

Most people who get question-banned are not like you. You (as evidenced by the very fact that this meta-question exists and isn't just a rant about what unfair jerks we are) are not the primary target of that autoban. You are the 1 in 10,000 and while it may sting personally remember there's a long tail of unobserved people for whom it is richly deserved.

### Now on to the actual answer:

Stack Overflow isn't just a website.

**It's a *culture.***

In addition to being something of a beast of its own, it also is enmeshed in the broader software engineering/hacker culture. While that might be worth teasing apart at some point in your journey, for right now you can safely conflate the two.

Like all cultures Stack Overflow has its own values and norms. Outsiders seeking to join the culture (again like any other culture) have to go through the process of *acculturation*, getting to know and internalize those values and norms. Now, you don't have to "go native" necessarily (unless you want to), but you *do* have to get far enough along not to commit social faux-pas if you wish to function effectively within the culture. Note that this is true even if you *vehemently disagree with those values and norms*.

You came to Stack Overflow with expectations of what that culture values and what the norms were/are, and you were wrong (which is fine; it's difficult to join a foreign culture). You tried to course-correct (awesome, keep doing that), but it didn't really work. I'm not sure where the breakdown happened; maybe you just thought of the rules as a bunch of bureaucracy instead of cultural norms and values that people actually care about. Maybe you did realize, but just hadn't quite caught on to the context and implications. I don't know, but I would again encourage you to keep trying to engage.

But even more than that, my advice is *don't take it personally*. **Don't take it personally**. I suspect that the overwhelming majority of the problems that people have here can be boiled down to "the Stack Overflow community did not validate my emotions *in the way I expected them to*". The community not only fails to do this; for the most part they make failing at this part of the mission.

Sometimes this is carried to an unhealthy [Torvalds-esque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds#Linux) extreme and Stack Overflow in particular lately has been trying to remedy this, but there's a lot of resistance for better or worse. I appreciate that some people use this as an excuse to be a jerk and that's bad, but seriously if people want their emotions validated they should attempt to get that IRL and not here. I'm human and need my emotions validated as much as the next person, but I don't (and shouldn't!) expect to get it from volunteer experts donating their time to help me with some highly technical question about file handles or whatever.

So, does Stack Overflow value self-learners? Yes. I'm a self-taught programmer (my degree is in English). I've never felt like I was rejected by the community. But I've had answers downvoted, questions closed, etc. There were a few bumps on my road to acculturation.

But you can't argue with the culture (any more than you can argue with an ethnic culture): you can engage with it on its terms or refuse to play. Note that engaging is not the same thing as approval: there are some values I share with Stack Overflow culture and some I don't. But I understand the collective actions of the community for what they are: a statement of values, *and valuable feedback about the culture*. I never took it (or at least tried very hard not to) take it as being about *me personally*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223674/discussion-on-answer-by-jared-smith-is-stack-overflow-a-good-place-for-self-lear).

Comment: this is absolutely spot on! In the couple of CS courses I had in undergrad SO was always presented as the forum to get answers to your questions. After about a year of using it, I've realized it is, in fact, a culture (one that I'm not particularly fond of, but that is very useful). I did conflate it with the programming culture, and from experience and anecdotes I know the programming culture is not alway the most welcoming of non-traditional programmers. thanks for this answer!

Comment: @alpablo20 " programming culture is not alway the most welcoming of non-traditional programmers" this is true but I feel it's important to remind people *why*: in the beginning the hacker culture was created largely by non-neurotypical people that society had shunned. A safe space in the parlance of today. I mention this because now that resistance is frequently brought up in terms of privilege. And in a world where the richest people are hacker nerds and The Avengers brings in literal billions at the box office then the accusation of privilege *maybe* makes some sense, but for those...

Comment: ...who remember being labelled "freak" (or worse) and wanting to kill themselves because they were such social pariahs I'm sure it seems pretty strange. I don't begrudge a culture wanting to maintain their values despite the world moving on (barring the obvious exceptions like FGM).

Answer (score 126):

Stack Overflow, in my experience, doesn't really *care* what kind of learner you are.

Stack Overflow cares only about:

- Did you ask a concise, reasonable question?
- Did you include as much relevant detail as you could at the time?
- Did you look around for duplicates?
- Did you look online/anywhere else for similar approaches before asking a question?

Q&A in general will brutalize you if you don't have concise, pithy questions to ask, and you're asking from more of a perspective of, "Oh, I don't really know how to do this, does anyone have any suggestions?"  That is because this invites **conversation**, and **conversation** is not Q&A.

So, I would say that Stack Overflow is fine for any kind of learner, but the expectation is that this learner comes to us having done their homework.

Comment: you're asking from more of a perspective of, "Oh, I don't really know how to do this, does anyone have any suggestions?" -- I'm not sure if youre referring to something I did specifically. If so, would you mind telling me where so I can be aware of it in the future?

Comment: Yeah, StackOverflow is great when you have enough of a mental model to be able to clearly describe the problem you're having and how it relates to concepts you are certain about. It sucks when you only have a vague notion of the solution you're trying to create, and a fuzzy mental model, and have no idea if you're even remotely on the right path, or if what you're trying to do is sensible at all, or if you don't know the right terms.

Comment: This. I learned how to program using Stack Overflow, so this is definitely a good place for self-learners. It just isn't a tutorial website or a real-time help desk.

Comment: @SteveBennett it's important to remember that there is a chat system within the Stack Overflow umbrella. This works differently for different languages but it does give some flexibility. I can only speak for the Python room but I would say that there is some scope to try crystalise ideas that might not be clear enough for the main site. There are, obviously, still guidelines but it's still an avenue.

Comment: @alpablo20:  I don't really think there's an answer to that statement that you're going to like.  If one feels like their questions are more of the form of conversation rather than Q&A, then in all actuality you would want for a tutor or teacher, and Peter's answer captures that essence very well indeed.  I wouldn't know where to tell you to start looking for a tutor or a teacher either, since, well...that's not my role here.  My role here is to provide answers to the reasonable questions you ask, and if you don't ask reasonable questions, there's not much I can do to help.

Comment: @SteveBennett:  I'm a software development team lead.  I get tons of vague questions all the time.  I cannot tell you how frustrating it can be to get vague questions from someone who instantly expects me to divine answers or solutions based on fluff.  It is imperative, as a show of respect for both the person you're asking advice from and to yourself in that you prove that you can be concise and communicate well, that you take the time to reduce as much fluff from the vague mental model that you have when you ask a question.

Comment: @SteveBennett:  It's unreasonable for someone to expect that you have the answer to a question before you ask it; no one's asking you to do that.  What *is* reasonable is that you've explored more than, say, one or two approaches on how to solve the problem, or you have more than one or two theories on what's going on.  If I have to present more theories or think through those with you, it's not a valuable use of my time, and it's not a show of respect to me or my time since it means that one cannot problem solve.  (And these days that's the only skill engineers really *require*.)

Comment: @roganjosh It may be a timezone thing, but I've never found any of the chat channels remotely useful. Maybe some people get lucky and happen to ask a question there at the exact time someone is around to answer, but it has never worked for me.

Comment: @SteveBennett indeed, coverage even for an active room like ours is Euro/US-centric :( People will still pick things up from the transcript when they become active again, so it defaults back to just asking a question on SO and having to wait. We still have a Room Owner from Australia, though, so there is definitely overlap. If you want to see activity levels you can look at the room info page e.g. [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python)

Answer (score 61):

From [Makoto's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402317):

> That is because this invites conversation, and conversation is not Q&A

Every sentence in that answer is chock-full of excellent advice. But *this* is the key, and I'd like to elaborate…

In particular, the conversation being invited is hand-holding, personalized tutorial and education. Which is also **not Q&A**. Stack Overflow isn't the place for someone to get personalized answers to their specific gaps of knowledge. There are just too many ways a person might fail to understand programming fundamentals, and it's **not useful** for the site to have different questions with answers for all those different ways. Doing so would require actual *teaching*, and actual teaching involves engaging the student, coming to an understanding about what that student knows and does not know, and providing tailored information to fill the gaps in that student's knowledge.

It also completely negates the whole goal of building a repository of useful questions and their answers. If every question is treated as unique, even when it's basically the same as a previously-answered question, then we're not building anything. We're just running a help desk.

If you are asking someone to tailor existing information for your own needs, **you're not self-learning!**

It's essential that a person posting a question to Stack Overflow:

1. Has already done an extensive search, both on the web and on Stack Overflow specifically, for an answer to their question
2. Has the ability to recognize that, while another person's question on Stack Overflow might not use an exact copy of the code they are using, the answer to their question is usually still there.

The second point requires a capacity for generalization, a critical skill for success in pretty much any field but *especially* in programming. Just because someone uses different variable names, or is writing a calculator demo instead of a checkers game, that doesn't mean that the same problems aren't involved in both.

All too often, a person complains that their question isn't a duplicate of the question that their question was just closed for, when in fact what they really mean is "that person's not writing the same program I'm writing". They ignore the fact that they have the *exact* same problem that other person has, just in a different context.

Finally, all of this requires some humility. The ability to, when someone tells you you're wrong, to accept that you might actually be wrong, and to be willing to spend thoughtful time exploring the ways in which you might be wrong, as well as the ways that person might be right.

Comment: The distinction between _answering_ and _teaching_ is quite profound, and I think highlights the difference between a Q&A site like SO and a forum like JavaRanch.

Comment: I fail to understand ***in any way, shape or form*** what on earth you or @Makoto are even alluding to when you say that "Question & Answers" are not "Conversation" - it's like ascribing new meanings to very basic constructs / words of the English Language to which nobody else on earth would agree.  NOBODY.  Questions and Answers are Conversations.  ***ASK ANYBODY !***  P.S. I am a strong dissenter to "curation" as censorship and believe it adds absolutely nothing to the value of this site except to the reputation of ***high rep users***.  NOTHING.

Comment: @Y2020-09, is Jeopardy a conversation?

Comment: @Y2020-09 I think the point here is that the Question/Answer format is not meant to be a back and forth conversation between users. It's meant to be one Question and one or more separate Answers, with minimal follow up. (Side note: You seem to have some good points, but I think the delivery is a bit rough.)

Comment: I **strongly** agree with the second point you said *Has the ability to recognize that, while another person's question on Stack Overflow might not use an exact copy of the code they are using, the answer to their question is usually still there*. A self-learner should have the ability to (and will benefit much more from) taking an answer that almost suits and do the necessary fine-tuning to make it work. On the other hand, I will be glad to answer a question showing the effort of that fine-tuning gone wrong, and asking help with that **specifically**...

Comment: If you are in the 4th grade science-magnet school, and just learned `System.out.println()` in Java, you are going to have to bring this up to a fifth grade level before we can give you answers...  If you are in the 9th grade, and just used your first `CSS Class`, it would be better to learn some 10th grade stuff before our community gives you any help.  If you just aced your college-prepatory CS exam, try taking some freshman year classes and get back to us.  If you are Junior Software Engineer, see if someone in your office can help, and ask on Stack Overflow **once you've got an answer.**

Comment: @Y2020-09: in relation to your first comment here, the view that there is a wide difference between Q&A and a conversation is fairly popular here on Meta Stack Overflow. Whether this accords with the meanings of the words in plain English probably isn't all that material - that is the ethic of the community, and the community generally takes the view that these are the rules.

Comment: Inventing new meanings for English Language Words on a site that routinely states this is an English Language Site perhaps ought to post a "Redefined Webster's Dictionary" that is in accordance with the meanings and usage rules agreed upon by the ***High Rep User Community*** here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Inviting Discussion" is how people learn - really is what I am trying to say.  It just ***happened to me again*** since the writing of this post - posting multiple answers because somebody ***really didn't get it***.  I was trying to help the guy.  "Future Users" are great, but the person who asks a question in the first place (the "OP") is ***a user, right now***.

Comment: This bears a lot of resemblance to the [top answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/4518341) on [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Comment: @Y2020-09 You are not wrong, in fact you are very right. And if SO was a helpdesk aimed at facilitating one-on-one tutoring/counseling, there wouldn't be a problem, at all. But thats fundamentally **not** what SO *is*. SO simply isn't a teaching site. It has a goal of building a Q&A repository. You are free trying to establish such a resource elsewhere -- but history has shown that the model SO follows ensures a high quality and interest in the site by experts - something more conversational sites often lack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223603/discussion-between-y2020-09-and-polygnome).

Answer (score 32):

Yes, Stack Overflow is an excellent resource for self-learners. I know because I’m one.

I learned to program in various languages way before Stack Overflow existed, but more recently I got reacquaintanted with C++, which is totally different now than it was 20 years ago; I am learning more advanced Python; I learned SQL; I learned Git; etc. All these things I learned mostly through Stack Overflow.

And I did all of that without posting any questions.

Stack Overflow is a repository of Q&A. You are supposed to find your answer there, not ask questions.

Only if, after exhausting all venues, you still don’t have an answer, then it is appropriate to add a question to the site. This question will then be well-researched and meaningful. Hopefully you can pose it in a sufficiently generic way that it is useful to many future visitors like you.

Comment: I agree. I would add: search with Google. It has SO indexed better then SO itself

Comment: And you can simply use "python list site:stackoverflow.com" (sans quotations) which will give you results only from stack overflow

Answer (score 12):

Stack Overflow is great in self-learning **only if** you have learned your basics somewhere else, got good grips on what you're doing, and then have specific question about some problem you encounter along the way. Starting from scratch in Stack Overflow does not quite work for me because of how generalized each answer is trying to be (they describe things well, but just not tailored for extreme beginners).

Stack Overflow also has taught me how to "find what is this problem called", because if I don't know what specific term that relates to my problem, I may not find the solution at all. And if I can know what that specific term is, probably there are already good answers about it.

The site also has taught me to find what is actually the problem I'm coming up against, because if I ask the wrong question, I may get the wrong answer (X-Y problem).

Comment: I'm curious to know how you do "find what is this problem called". I have the impression new users have difficulty with that exactly that aspect. If you can elaborate a bit on that part that would be useful.

Comment: Agreed. Knowing what the problem is called (or at least being able to describe it well) is definitely important for either finding an existing solution or asking an easier-to-understand question. Often it is dissecting specific keywords/phrases from error messages or from the combination of tool + desired action (eg. "css rounded corners" leads to the CSS "border-radius" property).

Comment: @rene at work our DBA and I have a running joke that we don't get paid for already knowing the answers, we get paid because we know enough to know what questions to ask. I don't think there's a shortcut to that: you learn it the hard/long way of using different tools in different problem-solving contexts over and over again. Or to put it in a different way for the purposes of meta SO, I kinda doubt it's something we can help too much with more than we already are.

Comment: Starting from scratch on Stack Overflow *does* work extremely well, since we have a *huge* library of existing Q&A for you to read and learn from. What doesn't work well is starting from scratch by *asking questions*. That's not how you start. You start by reading and searching. Then, if you have a question about what you read, you can ask a question about it. That question will almost certainly go over well, because it'll be specific, focused, and will include evidence of research. Heck, you can (and should) link *directly* to the other SO Q&A that you read and are asking about.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps some will care about my opinion:

I have been teaching at the computer science education at the university in my city for a variety of courses: Software development, introduction to programming, template math libraries with C++, computer systems (architecture, C, networking, and OS), and computer graphics.

When you teach, you get a lot of questions from students who panic - "Help, it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?" - where they simply pasted something and pressed compile. Over time I think, people tend to develop more resillience towards errors, and gradually learn to live with the pain and try to solve their problems themselves.

I have seen this pattern so many times.

I read a couple of your questions, and I think they are nice good questions. You obviously have spent time doing research, and you are coming from a place where you honestly just want to learn and understand. And that is what this is all about.

There are a lot of crappy tutorials on the Internet, and especially the Git workflow is often explained very poorly, though it is so simple to use when you get to learn it.

Perhaps Stack Overflow is not a place for beginners and tutorials, but more of an encyclopedia where precise technical difficulties are explained by other programmers in a professional manner. And if the way you ask questions is unprofessional, or you didn't spend enough time trying to solve it yourself / are being lazy, then you are showing an unprofessional attitude and thus you will get bashed.

I have experienced this myself many times, and I'm still learning.

Comment: How do you help your students (in the described situation)? Asking them rhetorical or leading questions?

Comment: I usually try to get them to answering their own questions but providing a lot of hints. When that doesn't work I explain everything very slowly up to the point where they got the error. Sometimes I get creative and invent hypothetical scenarios. If everything fails then I simply show them the correct answer and get them to explain to me why it is correct. But it also depends on the student. Some have more patience than others

Answer (score 8):

It's a great place for self-learners if you have enough **grit**.

- Tough skin, persistence, etc.
- The burning desire to figure something out.
- The hope to connect with someone on it, even though you know you will be on your own.

For common popular things, such as jQuery -

- There will be the brutal secretary types who will immediately delete your post because you did not know how to ask the question right.

"You might not see how it's similar - it's good to look through that to learn random other things that might not answer your question. And then re-phrase your question."

For bleeding edge tech, you might be the first person to ask the question. And, years later you will find yourself somehow upvoted thousands of times for these naive questions that everyone has while learning the new technology.

- Sometimes, even after asking a ton of questions that got up-voted, you may have naive questions and get extra down-voted for having a high score and asking a dumb question.

"Post comments asking why".

- And... There will be people who will downvote you just because.

"Read the part above about grit."

Comment: And (sadly) serial voting

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 serial voting usually gets reversed within 24 hours, and if it doesn't, you can always custom flag one of the votes and explain the situation to a moderator. Also, please remember that asking 3 lousy questions in fairly quick succession and getting downvoted on all of them isn't necessarily serial voting.

Comment: @MattDMo: Indeed, a series of votes is not serial voting. My personal definition hinges on this difference: is it a series of individual judgements (not serial voting) or is it a single judgement on a series of posts (serial voting)? If you come across a series of posts, and you look at each of them individually solely based on the quality of their content, and it just turns out that all of them are downvote-worthy, then it is not serial voting. If you look at a small sample of a series of posts and decide based on that small sample that the entire series is downvote-worthy, that is serial.

Comment: @Scratte sure, why not? I think you could find this info elsewhere on meta (it's where I've scraped it up over the years), but may as well not make things too easy...

Comment: Your definition of “grit” is what you need to have to be a self-learner. If you are not persistent, and don’t have a burning desire to figure something out, then you’re not a self-learner. You might attempt to learn something by yourself, but you never will. Nothing to do with SO.

Comment: Well, just saying that SO is a tough environment to learn in if you don't have grit. You don't need grit to be a self-learner - you can just passively watch free youtube videos etc... but you might not survive on SO.

Answer (score 7):

TLDR: YES.

Learning programming is hard. It's hard whether you're being taught by yourself or someone else. It's different than some other subjects, because often you don't simply have to learn how something works, and you have to learn an entirely new way of thinking before you can do that. It's time consuming, because it takes practice to wrap your mind around the different ways of thinking about problems, and to learn to recognize patterns within those systems of thought that can apply to your specific problem. People's aptitude for this varies, so some people will need less practice than others, but there is no substitute for the practice.

I think this is why some people have trouble using Stack Overflow as a learning resource. Without realizing or accepting that fact, many people start to ask questions here before they have put enough time and effort into learning, and they generally have a bad time. The problem is that people usually don't have a good idea of how much they don't understand, so it's difficult for them to figure out whether or not they know enough to even be able to ask a good question. I don't think that's really their fault, and I also don't think there's much that Stack Overflow can do about it. It's just an unfortunate aspect of this kind of learning.

However, that does not mean that Stack Overflow is not a good place for self learners. It will just be useful in different ways depending on where you are in the learning process. When you are just starting on learning a language or framework, especially if it's your first time programming, it will mostly be useful to read existing questions and answers. Most beginner questions have already been asked and answered, although it definitely can be challenging to know what to search for if you don't know what the thing you need is called. If you ask an answerable question at this point, there's a good chance it will be closed as a duplicate.

After you've gotten a better grasp of what you're learning, it will become more useful to ask questions. Ironically, by that time you won't have as many questions, so you probably won't need to do it very often. I think this can actually be used as an indicator of whether you should ask a question here. If you have a lot of questions all the time, you're probably still in the "mostly useful for reading" phase. Gradually you'll find that you're able to answer questions as well, which can also be a valuable learning tool, but as you learn you'll also get better at finding existing answers, so many times the answer will be a reference to a duplicate question.

Most of this answer isn't specifically aimed at you. It's just my thoughts on the topic in general. After looking through a few of your posts, it looks like you're already farther along than a lot of people who start asking questions, and you write well, which is always helpful. Based on my own experience using this site to help teach myself programming, I think it looks like you'll do fine here. Just be patient.

Comment: "The problem is that people usually don't have a good idea of how much they don't understand, so it's difficult for them to figure out whether or not they know enough to even be able to ask a good question" this right here is part of what I was getting at. I think I have a better idea of how to use SO now. But I do think in general the programming community has a bad rep of being unwelcoming of beginners or non-traditional learners. And it'd be great if we were more welcoming of newbies! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

There's some history here - upon launch SO was supposed to be a community for *professional and enthusiast programmers*. That is, a site to help already somewhat established programmers with at least mediocre skill or better. With the definition of a programmer being a person who at least knows the basics of at least one programming language.

Basically if you had read a beginner-level book and/or taken beginner-level classes about the language your question was about, you were good to go. And the other way around, if you had not even studied the most basic beginner-level learning material such as the first chapters of a book, then you would not receive a warm welcome.

A lot of the veteran users signed up during this initial "a site for programmers" era.

Then after various CEO and policy changes, the site slowly changed into more of a "quantity over quality" mindset. Aiming to be a site where people would stumble in from Google to get quick answers, without having to stop and care about the site or its quality over time. The requirement that a person would actually have to know the basics of the topic they were asking about was removed.

SO was always a place to learn programming - as in a place where a programmer could ask a specific, technical question to other programmers. But somewhere around then, some misguided notion that the site was a place to learn the uttermost basics started. This was never the intention, SO is *not* an interactive beginner tutorial.

If someone uses the site as "trying out some basic stuff at a whim" -> "ask on SO when it isn't working" -> "repeat", then SO is a horrible place for learning because it was never designed for this purpose. Furthermore, learning programming by trial & error is also a pretty bad idea, because there's so much which you simply can't learn just from fooling around - you have to study at least the basics from a consistent, reliable source of learning. Also you'll want to avoid picking up misconceptions and bad practices.

The way to reliably learn programming is as follows:

- Get the basic prerequisites straight. That is, basic computer knowledge, basic English knowledge, basic math knowledge, the binary/hex number systems. You need to have basic knowledge of all these things before writing your first line of code.

  And in case of using SO/the Internet, basic human-to-human communication skills are also required.
- Get a reliable source of learning such as a good book and/or classes. Preferably updated at least during the current millennium.

  Big warning: Internet tutorials have very diverse quality and any fool can post one, or post some crap on Youtube for that matter. There may be good tutorials online, but regard everything said with great scepticism.
- Using your source of learning, first study a chapter, then do the exercises given. Modify them, play around with them. And if you fancy, start some programming project on the side and improve it as you learn more. Ultimately you learn programming by coding.
- When you get stuck:

  1. Check your source of learning, as well as relevant manuals/technical documentation.
  2. If still not clear, you can search on SO/the Internet for questions about a similar problem.
  3. If you still find nothing good while searching, then you can ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I think that SO is a good place for self-learners, but it is highly recommended to take a course about the language/framework before asking if the time allows it. This offers several advantages:

- a more profound understanding of that framework's way of thinking
- the why behind many aspects that the framework solves
- you know how various concepts are named and be able to issue more relevant searches (btw, use Google instead of site search, because it provides better results)

From my personal experience and other fellow programmers' one, it is quite hard to get beyond a certain point without a more systematic approach. Good courses integrate lots of concepts and best-practices that require dozens and dozens of SO questions and answers to get them covered.

**tldr**

If you want to seriously learn, consider SO as a complementary resource rather than the single/primary one. Also, consider using a search engine that might provide more interesting results (e.g. articles).

Answer (score 2):

> I asked a question and not five minutes after posting, it got marked as duplicate and closed...

Some time ago I asked a question, which was closed as a duplicate almost immediately. And I was very happy indeed. Why? Because I got the answer I needed in less than a minute.

Being closed as a duplicate means you have your answer (sometimes several), right away. That's a good thing.

Comment: This point of view is astonishingly positive. Imagine all those unanswered questions that no one even cares to find the dupes of!

Comment: This "answer" is not an answer but a comment. A good comment (i.e. I like it). But [someone else already posted it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402293/is-stack-overflow-a-good-place-for-self-learners?cb=1#comment803996_402293)!

Answer (score 1):

As someone who, along many many others, grew up with Stack Overflow to get help for hobby projects and now has a job as a developer:

**YES**.

Despite all the bad stuff the company has done, Stack Overflow is still an invaluable resource base. The information found on this site is literally worth billions of dollars if you value in the time and the effort contributors have made.

And also, don't worry if your first (20) questions or answers are terrible. I was downvoted to oblivion in 2014 when I wrote comments as answers and such, but who cares? You will improve and become what you've always wanted.

Answer (score 1):

As a self-learner I have found SO to be incredibly difficult as well. I feel defeated when I see: Your question is a duplicate, it has been marked as not useful and the question is closed. See this question instead.

But, the important thing to realize here is that just because your question was closed, doesn't mean it was a bad question, and I wish SO made a distinction between the two. I always spend a lot of time researching my problems and only ever ask a question on SO as a last resort. But a lot of the time I still ask a duplicate question, because I didn't know enough about the issue to search for the right answer or I couldn't make the connection between what I was reading and my own problem. But when someone says, this is your error, that connection is a lot easier to make. Now, as other's have said, that may not be the type of site SO wants to be, but if that's how the user base uses this site, it is the site you are.

I hate picking on [Peter Duniho](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402320/4175929) because he has helped me out a lot in the last few days (by closing my questions and pointing me in the right direction), but this:

> it's not useful for the site to have different questions with answers
> for all those different ways

couldn't be further from the truth, the vast majority of the time I find a solution, it's because I found a post that was closed and marked as a duplicate. However, it was that post that asked the question similar to how I would have asked, that led me to the post that I wouldn't have found because I wasn't asking the question the same way as the original. I know this happens a lot because those duplicates are often upvoted for this same reason.

Comment: Duplicates aren't a bad thing (unless they are obvious duplicates that show that you didn't even bother to google your problem). This is how the site is supposed to work... If you had a hard time finding the question that means others will also have a hard time so if you ask a question (which you will ask in a way that might be new and easier to find) then (even if it is marked as a duplicate) it will work as a signpost to the *harder to find* post ;)

Comment: What might help in your questions is stating what you searched for (aka what search terms you used) and then explain for two or three results why they don't address your problem. There are two benefits from that: future visitors that make the same mental leap will find your question so it will be an awesome signpost; someone might explain what is wrong and/or how you ended up with your search terms. This will help you improve your search skills.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow, I guess, is a good place for self learners; you save time (you don't do a whole course just to know something) and you save money (some courses aren't free).

For me personally, it is a good place to search up some little error or something, but if it's a mini-project or project you should probably take a course.

Answer (score -14):

Stack Overflow is a tool which is used by the community. The tool is not responsible for its usage. The usage of tool and its effectiveness purely depends on user (their raising, education, health, etc.).

So, I'd second the answer of [@Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402317/5113030).

---

Although, of course, almost every tool accepts improvements and that's why the development exists.

That said, if you find your questions answered here and you're satisfied with it, then it works. What else do a self-learning person need, except proper answers and suggestions?

Some might say education is a life-wide and lifelong learning process. The speed and effectiveness of this process depends on raising.

> "Tell me and I forget, teach me and I may remember, involve me and I
> learn." - Xunzi, Xun Kuang, 312-230 BC

Comment: To suggest that what I was saying was that the benefit of the tool depends on the user suggests that you haven't actually read my answer.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, what? I didn't reference you about the tool, but the idea that  `Stack Overflow cares only about`(the effectiveness of usage).

Comment: I agree with you. And I think StackOverflow has gradually developed towards (and will continue to) a place of professionalism. We don't really have an official encyclopedia for programmers and programming techniques, but this forum is probably the closest thing. StackOverflow is **not** a learning book for a course at school.