# Can you ask questions of the form “What is X?”

Tags: discussion, scope

Lately, I have been asking more canonical questions on Stack Overflow, rather than highly particular ones based on difficulty with achieving some multi-part goal.

These are usually received better because when you step back and reformulate the problem in clear language and general terms, and break it down into a question about a single concept, the question has way more usefulness to other people as well.

I also try to ask and answer my own questions. Similar to the rubber duck principle, when I externalize my current roadblock / goal as a clearly formulated question, I see my goal in a much clearer and more organized way. I then spend the next hour or so reading documentation until I have thoroughly answered my own question and made sure I have also filled in any small supporting details to make sure my understanding of the topic is holistic and well-rounded, and not just an obscure line of code that works but doesn’t show depth of understanding and may still hinder you going forward.

So once I started asking way more canonical reference questions and also answering them canonically, instead of sort of begging for help in confused situations due to inexperience, I have got more upvotes.

I would like to extend that tendency to make sure I am asking myself every question I can think of to have complete understanding by even asking very fundamental questions like “What is X?”

For example, many, many programmers know what Vim is, but if you’re completely new to Vim, you might benefit from a clear, simple, direct answer to the question “What is Vim?” in the way that more advanced users benefit from more advanced but similar questions like “What are dynamic types?” or something.

I think the argument for such questions is that they are genuinely useful if you don’t know what something is, and they fit in with the spirit of easy Stack Overflow questions like “How do I do multiline comments in Python?”.

I personally would like to ask such questions because similar to the examples above they force you to ask yourself if you actually understand something. When I try to answer “What is Vim?” or “What is Python?”, I have to think about and research objective and precisely detailed information such as:

- When was it invented, and by who?
- What did the creators state was the core premise, vision, aim or design philosophy for it?
- What objective characteristics does it have? What classifiable features does it have, compared to similar things?
- How does it work, briefly? In other words, what is Vim, as a program? What language is it written in, and what happens when you launch Vim? What does the initialization entail, and what is the drop-in point of their user interface?

These are two questions that have got closed, but have lots of upvotes, and which I think are similar:

[What is Python used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909512/what-is-python-used-for)

[What is in your .vimrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164847/what-is-in-your-vimrc)

Arguments against such questions could be that there could be too many answers. Since it’s not a problem with a single solution, there wouldn’t be the same sense of being “answered”, and therefore not needing another answer. The answers might have some level of subjectivity to them, although in principle the question can be approached objectively.

Do you think those kinds of questions should or could be asked, and if not, what specific criterion do you think moderators would cite for why it doesn’t fit the site? Because it’s not a problem needing a solution, or because there could be too many answers, or because they think it’s too obvious?

Comment: Questions like "What is X" are readily and reliably answered through web search. They are not usually specific enough to be of much use on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's difficult to, as a single data point, determine what questions will be useful if well answered to a large number of people. You're gonna have hits and misses even if you're very careful in what you do and don't post if you're asking questions that you don't actually need an answer to. If you were instead asking questions that you *don't* know the answer to, then there's at least one person out there with the question who couldn't find it in search. Chances are there's another, if it's not specific to your code.

Comment: "I have to think about and research objective and precisely detailed information such as" If your single question already implies 4 full blown questions, that looks very much like lacking focus.

Comment: Similar (identical?): [*What is the meaning of X?* or *What does X mean?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175151/). [Another *explaining* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663097/gcc-lm-lz-lrt-options-what-are-they-about) (*"What are these things?"* and *"What does this mean?"*).

Comment: Your bulleted questions are not on-topic. Votes from lazy google-averse newcomers to the site & topic is not a signal of good Q&A. It's too bad that the "research effort" downvote reason gets in the way of canonical self-answered questions. But the fact is despite SO Inc's aversion it is necessary to RTFM before one starts something. Also what is X is not a specific programming problem, there is no context. The site might better have been called Stuck Overflow.

Comment: [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655382/meaning-of-gcc-o2) [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164707/whats-the-meaning-of-gcc-c-and-gcc-o) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398522/what-is-the-o-option-in-gcc).

Comment: [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290131/how-does-gccs-pg-flag-work).

Comment: Another example (2012): *[What is E in floating point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687016)*. An answerer [got the Lifeboat badge yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat?page=1).

Comment: Another example: *[What is JavaScriptExecutor in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689880/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium)*

Answer (score 15):

No, please don't do this.  None of those questions are [practical and answerable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to the field of software development.

We're not going to be a repository for trivia or history nuggets, and catching lightning in a bottle in which somehow the maintainer of that application or language or service [comes to answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55884514/1079354) doesn't mean we can bank on it again.

Answer (score 13):

Do not ask anything in the main site *as someone who knows nothing* about programming as Stack Overflow is for anyone **who writes code**, meaning, askers should already have the *elemental digital literacy* that makes them able to write code. Stack Overflow isn't intended to be an introductory course, tech / [science communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_communication) material, dictionary, lexicon, encyclopedia, vocabulary or any other form of general knowledge repository. It isn't a place to ask about theory in an academic sense, and it isn't a place to ask about the origins of programming as a reporter or historian.

It might be possible that some definitions or descriptions may be necessary to be clear about what is being asked and answered, or to provide proper usage guidance for tags and other site features, but besides the description of the Stack Overflow artifacts, this site isn't intended to be the authoritative or reference source for programming concepts and isn't intended to serve *anyone on the web*. It isn't intended to solve the digital gap / divide.

Such questions should be closed as

> **Not about programming or software development**
>
> Use this close reason if the question is not about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers.

If you like to contribute around *terms*, *definitions* and *facts*, it's fine, look at Meta and the [tag-wiki](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki), existing questions and answers. There might be content that could be added or improved but don't try to compete against or replicate the work of well-established authoritative and reference sources.

If the content is related to one of the [collectives](/questions/tagged/collectives), you might propose [articles](/questions/tagged/articles).

Another possible course of action is, once you identify a common misconception or form of *X-Y Problem*, you might work with SMEs to create a canonical question resembling the common form / typical case and answer the question explaining the relevant concepts to understand what was misunderstood that lead many programmers to that form of misconception / *X-Y Problem*.

---

Related

- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/289691)
- [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/1595451)
- [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1595451)
- [Is Stack Overflow a good place for self learners?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402293/1595451)
- [Community input needed: The guidelines for collectives articles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413357/1595451)
- [Off-Topic Help Requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421191/1595451) (answer to [Staging Ground Workflow: Canned Comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420897/1595451))

---

From Computer Science Educators

- [What is a file?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/5551/12659)

  - This question was posted by a CS teacher and is about how to answer this a student question.
- [What is standard definition of Computer Science](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/7506/12659)

Comment: What is *science difussion*? *defussing*? *[diffusion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diffusion#Noun)* (could be covered by *"6. The spread of cultural or linguistic practices, or social institutions, in one or more communities."*)? *[defuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/fuzzing)* (in some sense)? The opposite of *"[fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion)"*? Something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was trying to say "divulgación científica". The Wikipedia article in Spanish is linked to "popular science", but I don't think that is correct, IMHO it should be linked to [science communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_communication).

Answer (score 6):

Some of the information you're trying to  contribute to the community like

- When was it invented, and by who?
- What did the creators state was the core premise, vision, aim or design philosophy for it?

can be added to the tag wiki.

For example, *What is Vim?*. The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vim/info) says,

> Vim is a free and open source text editor with a steep learning curve that leads to high efficiency in many tasks related to text editing. If you wish to start with Vim, run :help vimtutor in Vim or run the vimtutor command in shell, which will teach you basic commands.

Similarly in case of [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), for the question, *Who invented Python?*, the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) says,

> Python was originally created by Guido van Rossum and was first released in 1991. Guido van Rossum chose Python as a working title for the project, being in a slightly irreverent mood (and a big fan of Monty Python's Flying Circus).

> Python 2 (16 October 2000 - 01 January 2020) has officially been sunset, and Python 3 (3 December 2008) is the only supported, maintained, and improved major version as of 01 January 2020