# Is it allowed to ask basic and general questions?

Tags: support, scope

I wonder if I'm allowed to ask questions that's not related to technology or programming and is nonspecific on Stack Overflow. For example, I wanted to ask a question about how to write a program in a good way or how to be familiar with things like Quectel, [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), expression parser, [Apex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce#Salesforce_Platform) workload to [Swoole](https://www.swoole.co.uk/docs/), [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly), etc. (Those are examples I took from questions shown on the Stack Overflow homepage).

I mean, how people even find it in the first place or like how they know it and even the words are still too complex to me.

So can I ask these types of questions on Stack Overflow? Or are there any other sites on the Stack Exchange network for me to ask such questions?

Comment: Basic questions, like "How do I add 2 integer values together in language *X*?" sure, but make sure you do the research first. Such questions can often be answered by a "quick" search in your favourite search engine, and often have (multiple) duplicates, so can be received poorly by the community. For "general" questions, this sounds like it's too broad or would lack focus. "How do I write in a good way?", is *extremely* open ended and more likely to result in opinions than anything else, which is off topic for [so].

Comment: Whether you are allowed to or not at this point in time is kind of a moot point IMO. The rules say yes, but the other rules say no. Other rules like: questions need to be unique. Basic questions are already asked and answered, so assume you can't ask your basic question. Search for it instead.

Comment: So there is absolutely no place on both stackoverflow and stackexchange to sumbit that kind of question

Comment: No, reddit or quora would be a better fit for questions like that

Comment: @ddier you don't need to, it's already answered. You need to do research. That is the whole point of Stack Overflow - to get to a point where you don't even need to ask anymore, the answer is already there.

Comment: The current version of Stack Overflow is not well suited for directed learning. Any learning that takes place is incidental. Though the company [has indicated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwpFzAR4FX4&t=23m20s) it is something they want to pursue (*"The users: learners, from beginners to experts"* and *"Community. Learning, sharing, and growing together"*).

Comment: Further, [at 23 min 38 secs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwpFzAR4FX4&list=PLX8jr8KmM50aaaHp7mP-iWaz7UZC8pbRK&t=23m38s) (I am not sure where the commas, or even full stops, should be near the end. My emphasis): *"Our outcomes are* ***not just a library.*** *But it is actually a community of people writing, consuming, curating, recommending, bringing in outside pieces of content altogether that will create a thriving community."*.

Comment: [At 25 min 10 secs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwpFzAR4FX4&list=PLX8jr8KmM50aaaHp7mP-iWaz7UZC8pbRK&t=25m10s) (my emphasis): New types of content: Articles, ***courses,*** blogs, and challenges.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Do you know if there is a public roadmap related to "new types of content"?

Comment: @Rubén: Not that I am aware of. But I haven't looked for it. I will keep watching.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR: Basic questions are "on-topic" but often won't be received well. General questions are likely too broad.

---

There is nothing technically wrong with "basic" questions, however, such questions can often be poorly received by the community. The reason for this is explained in the downvote tooltip:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

For "basic" questions, the likelihood that the question can be answered by a quick search in your favourite search engine is pretty high; "How do I add 2 integer values in C#" would give you a wealth of answers. This would mean that many users are likely to see the question as lacking research effort.

Such questions also are likely duplicates; many of the "basic" questions have been asked and answered many years ago when Stack Overflow was in its infancy and when online documentation was much more sparse. As such it's unlikely that a "basic" question will be seen as useful either,  especially when duplicates exist.

This is *not* to say that there won't be *good/well received* basic questions in the future; a new language could come out, which has very poor documentation. In such a scenario Stack Overflow could well be a great place to ask such questions, however, I would wonder about the "sanity" of those that want to use a language that is so poorly documented.

---

For "general" questions, as I mentioned in my comment, these don't sound like good questions for the site. Questions need to be specific, and this doesn't sound like they would be. They could easily be too broad or lack focus, resulting in closure.

To repeat my comment, the example you give "How do I write in a good way?", is extremely open-ended and more likely to result in opinions than anything else, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: "however, I would wonder about the "sanity" of those that want to use a language that is so poorly documented." - Ha! Yet half the world uses Javascript and its thousands of poorly documented libraries written by individuals in their spare time :) The code is the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

> how to write a program in a good way or how to be familiar with things like Quectel

The main problem with such questions is that they lack good answers. To fit the Q&A answer format, a question should allow clear and well-defined answers. Sometimes that may be 3 lines, sometime 30 lines. But a good answer answers the whole question, and not a lot more (it's reasonable to add a section to an answer to address obvious extensions to the question).

To reflect on just the first part: "how to write a program in a good way?" A good answer should be a complete answer, but how do you completely answer *that*?! You can write an entire book about it! (E.g., Kernighan and Pike's book, *[The Practice of Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Practice_of_Programming)*)

Answer (score 3):

Stop worrying about if "a basic question" is allowed on Stack Overflow. Instead, learn to find what you need to know, what you need to be able to do and what you need to do to get that knowledge and skills.

The above isn't broadly supported on Stack Overflow (the main site) and in the Stack Exchange network. You might find directions about certain topics in the corresponding tag wikis, you might find chat rooms where might be OK to ask basic and general questions, and you might find Stack Exchange sites explicitly allow questions from students for certain topics, like *[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour)* where programming questions are off-topic.

In general, the best is to go to an **educative center**. It might be brick and mortar or a digital/virtual, **take a training** / workshop / boot camp / course, ask for "do it yourself" / educative / career **advice**, somewhere else, not on the SO main site. **Learn** to *read*, learn to *search*, and learn to *ask good questions*.

Notes:

1. Questions about self-learning, how to teach yourself about the topics you mentioned and what exercises might help, could be asked on [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com). Just bear in mind that compared with Stack Overflow, it is a small site (that have very few questions/answers by day).
2. For guidance about where to ask questions not about technology and programming, ask for a site recommendation on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

---

As I mentioned in [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421248/1595451) to [Can you ask questions of the form “What is X?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421242/1595451)

> Do not ask anything in the main site *as someone who knows nothing* about programming as Stack Overflow is for anyone **who writes code**, meaning, askers should already have the *elemental digital literacy* that makes them able to write code. Stack Overflow isn't intended to be an introductory course, tech / [science communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_communication) material, dictionary, lexicon, encyclopedia, vocabulary or any other form of general knowledge repository.

On Stack Overflow questions are not classified as "basic", "easy", "beginner", etc., other than "open", "closed", "answered", "has accepted answer", and "deleted".

There isn't any problem to ask things that you might think that are "basic" or that are "easy" for someone else. The "problem" is to ask *bad questions*.

Asking a really *excellent question* requires a strong background (knowledge and skills). Asking a **good question** requires having a good background and might require specific work like doing focused research (read / search / write / review / try). To ask a good question is not necessary to be an expert in everything, but good questions can't be done by someone who knows nothing.

Please bear in mind that excellent and good questions might not get an answer. This might happen for several reasons, but the most important might be to get the attention of the right people, but this is something to discussed in another question.